fstab, mountpoint - what did I miss?
I can't figure out what I'm missing or done wrong.
lsblk dose not show the mount points(?)
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part
sdb           8:16   1 119.1G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   1 119.1G  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 118.6G  0 part /

Meanwhile services such as SMB/SAMBA dependent on those disk/drivs being mounted are working as intended!
so I have to do a sudo mount -a after each startup.. here is the output from lsblk after doing so
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/Pi5-NAS
sdb           8:16   1 119.1G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   1 119.1G  0 part /mnt/Backup
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 118.6G  0 part /

Could this be cause of the subfolders (aka the Mountpoints) within /mnt/ are not owned by root?
ls -l / ; ls -l /mnt/
total 64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Mar 15 15:59 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr 27 16:55 boot
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  4380 May  4 14:27 dev
drwxr-xr-x  97 root root  4096 May  4 15:17 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 15 16:00 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Mar 15 15:59 lib -> usr/lib
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Mar 15 16:08 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 15 15:59 media
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May  4 03:08 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May  2 00:03 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 214 root root     0 May  4 14:27 proc
drwx------   5 root root  4096 May  4 00:21 root
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root   740 May  4 14:42 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Mar 15 15:59 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 15 15:59 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root root     0 May  4 14:27 sys
drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 May  4 16:01 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Apr 30 10:38 uhubctl
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Mar 15 15:59 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Apr 27 16:53 var
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 May  4 02:57 Backup
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 May  3 23:07 Pi5-NAS

cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=3986f1d4-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=3986f1d4-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
PARTUUID=417eda08-9bf8-3445-ad9c-3bd49168c167 /mnt/Pi5-NAS ext4 defaults 0 0
PARTUUID=b3a9a096-86af-324a-8347-6d8d5765b789 /mnt/Backup ext4 defaults 0 0
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that

Here is all the outputs I could think of posting in this regard.. and all of these outputs below are before running sudo mount -a.
sudo ls -l /dev/sd*; sudo ls -l /dev/nvme*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 May  4 14:27 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 May  4 14:27 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 May  4 14:27 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 May  4 14:27 /dev/sdb1
crw------- 1 root root 245, 0 May  4 14:27 /dev/nvme0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 May  4 14:27 /dev/nvme0n1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 May  4 14:27 /dev/nvme0n1p1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 2 May  4 14:27 /dev/nvme0n1p2

lsblk -S -p
NAME     HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL      REV SERIAL           TRAN
/dev/sda 1:0:0:0    disk WD Blue  SN580 2TB 0    240205804034     usb
/dev/sdb 0:0:0:0    disk SanDisk  SDDR-B531 2920 0719220000001828 usb

lsblk -P -p
NAME="/dev/sda" MAJ:MIN="8:0" RM="0" SIZE="1.8T" RO="0" TYPE="disk" MOUNTPOINTS=""
NAME="/dev/sda1" MAJ:MIN="8:1" RM="0" SIZE="1.8T" RO="0" TYPE="part" MOUNTPOINTS=""
NAME="/dev/sdb" MAJ:MIN="8:16" RM="1" SIZE="119.1G" RO="0" TYPE="disk" MOUNTPOINTS=""
NAME="/dev/sdb1" MAJ:MIN="8:17" RM="1" SIZE="119.1G" RO="0" TYPE="part" MOUNTPOINTS=""
NAME="/dev/nvme0n1" MAJ:MIN="259:0" RM="0" SIZE="238.5G" RO="0" TYPE="disk" MOUNTPOINTS=""
NAME="/dev/nvme0n1p1" MAJ:MIN="259:1" RM="0" SIZE="512M" RO="0" TYPE="part" MOUNTPOINTS="/boot/firmware"
NAME="/dev/nvme0n1p2" MAJ:MIN="259:2" RM="0" SIZE="118.6G" RO="0" TYPE="part" MOUNTPOINTS="/"

mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3950848k,nr_inodes=246928,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=824576k,mode=755)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=4444)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/firmware type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=824560k,nr_inodes=206140,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)

sudo fdisk -x
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: THNSN5256GPU7 TOSHIBA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3986f1d4

Device         Boot   Start       End   Sectors Id Type            Start-C/H/S   End-C/H/S Attrs
/dev/nvme0n1p1         8192   1056767   1048576  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)      64/0/1   1023/3/32
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1056768 249737215 248680448 83 Linux             1023/3/32 1023/127/63


Disk /dev/sdb: 119.08 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Disk model: SDDR-B531
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EF6D1978-32E1-0E40-9979-AFFB0436BABC
First usable LBA: 2048
Last usable LBA: 249737182
Alternative LBA: 249737215
Partition entries starting LBA: 2
Allocated partition entries: 128
Partition entries ending LBA: 33

Device     Start       End   Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/sdb1   2048 249737182 249735135 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 B3A9A096-86AF-324A-8347-6D8D5765B789


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: SN580 2TB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6A12D386-0B82-5243-9A71-4CABBDF2B271
First usable LBA: 2048
Last usable LBA: 3907029134
Alternative LBA: 3907029167
Partition entries starting LBA: 2
Allocated partition entries: 128
Partition entries ending LBA: 33

Device     Start        End    Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/sda1   2048 3907028991 3907026944 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 417EDA08-9BF8-3445-AD9C-3BD49168C167

I don't know if this is necessary but if so:
SBC: Raspberry Pi 5 - OS: Raspberry Pi OS Lite - System: 64-bit Kernel version: 6.6 - Distribution: Debian version: 12 (bookworm)

my two cents:
the default parameters in the two fstab entries
PARTUUID=417eda08-9bf8-3445-ad9c-3bd49168c167 /mnt/Pi5-NAS ext4 defaults 0 0
PARTUUID=b3a9a096-86af-324a-8347-6d8d5765b789 /mnt/Backup ext4 defaults 0 0

may need to be changed
PARTUUID=417eda08-9bf8-3445-ad9c-3bd49168c167 /mnt/Pi5-NAS ext4 noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.device-timeout=2 0 0
PARTUUID=b3a9a096-86af-324a-8347-6d8d5765b789 /mnt/Backup ext4 noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.device-timeout=2 0 0

as described in this other answer

Please elaborate cause my understanding is that defaults contains following = rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async furthermore since the drives are mounted (in my secnario usable/accessible) even though not listed in lsblk then it means nofail wouldn't have any effect, or?

you are right - I have changed the options to match the ones suggested in this other answer

Well I add nofail and the situation remains the same. Also I read that post and the comments. But I wont attempt involving systemd into the mix cause in my experience wherever systemd is involved there will be longer boot times and or even worst, no boot at all or lots of fails during boot up. My somewhat "bad" experience is however not based in by actual practice of combing systemd in fstab and the mounting process. So maybe the suggested configuration setup will work and solve it but I cant bet on it. Nevertheless I did give your answer an up vote and it might as well be the only solution.
